# Is there an application deployment service you can install on kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, google-kubernetes-engine

This is a software suggestion question.
I have a pair of production-staging kubernetes clusters with like 7-10 deployments each deployed at GKE. Some of deployments exposed as network endpoints group and connected to Google Cloud Load Balancer as backends. These backends used in host and path prefix mappings.

What I looking for is something like that:

1. can create or replace deployment from git url and credentials or from uploaded code archive (preferrable both, or option to specify path within repo instead of uploading code archive.
2. Can create or replace pairing `service` for deployment.
3. Can configure GKE-compatible HPA (horisontal pod autoscaler for deployment).
4. can run command line commands before image building like private NPM repo setup or webpack usage and packed markup etc upload before building image
5. must have combination of deployment service within cluster and corresponding CLI for initiating these deployments from locally cloned GIT repos.
6. must have authentication to make sure only requests from known developers can deploy to clusters.
7. command line parameters must be minimalistic, like for deployment - image id, deployment/service id, way to expose (service or network endpoints), instances default count, option to enable pod autoscaler with min-max range of instances, whether to run webpack.
8. ability to create git tags automatically to relate deployments with code versions from repo.
9. should have a support in-repo configuration files with way specify these parameters, to be able to run just command like `deploy-it new-git-tag` started from directory where `Dockerfile` present.

OMG, that is a long list of features and requirements.

I asking that because i actually created a in-house solution like service described, but I look to switch to something "ready" and "battle tested" to concentrate on "application-level" code instead of maintaining this "infrastructure" code we have in our project.
Current solution also is "headless", GKE management UI used instead of some own UI to monitor deployments.

Comment: Software suggestion questions are explicitly not allowed on Stack Overflow, since they tend to attract opinionated answers rather than technical facts.  Also see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Could you suggest a place you know as suitable for this question to be asked?

Answer (score 0):

nable pod autoscaler with min-max range of instances, whether to run webpack. ability to create git tags automatically to relate deployments with code versions from repo. should have a [Pubg Name Generator](https://pubfonts.com/) support in-repo configuration files with way specify these parameters, to beThis is a software suggestion question. I have a pair of production-staging kubernetes clusters with like 7-10 deployments each deployed at GKE. Some of deployments exposed as network endpoints group and connected to Google Cloud Load Balancer as backends. These backends used in host and path prefix mappings

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34805812)